# onGoogleApiLoaded not rendering when state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, google-maps-react

I have a `<GoogleMapReact>` component, and I render some circles on the map by a list of points, using `onGoogleApiLoaded`:

```
const tags = [allJobsTag].concat(settings.jobs.filter((job) => !job.deleted));
const [tag, setTag] = useState(allJobsTag);

function renderGeoFences(map, maps) {
    _.map(geoFencesSites, (site) => {
        let circle = new maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: tag.id==='all-jobs'?"orange":'#1aba8b26',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            fillColor: '#1aba8b1f',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            map,
            center: { lat: Number(site.location.latitude), lng: Number(site.location.longitude) },
            radius: site.fenceSize,
        });
    });
}




let apiIsLoaded = (map, maps) => {
    renderGeoFences(map, maps);
};

return(
    <GoogleMapReact>
        zoom={getMapZoom()}
        center={{ lat: centerLatitude, lng: centerLongitude }}
        options={{
            fullscreenControl: false,
            zoomControlOptions: { position: 3 },
        }}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps)}
    >
        {renderAddresses()}
        {renderUsersLocation()}
        {renderHighlightedUserRoute()}
    </GoogleMapReact>
)
```

and then rendering the circles in `renderGeoFences`.

However, this function is only called ones, and even though there are states in it, the circles would not be affected by the state.
like in this example, when I try to change to color of the circles by the tag.id (tag is a state).
How can I make this function render again when a state is changing?

Comment: Can you post the whole component? And please format it.

Comment: @Elias thank you for your feedback. I added the 'renderGeoFences' function.

Comment: I formatted the code for you in the proposed edit :). After doing so a few things strike me as curious. 1. `apiIsLoaded` seems like some sort of check, but nothing is returned from it and it will always be undefined. 2. `apiIsLoaded` could be removed and `renderGeoFences` called directly.

Comment: I never see you setting any state. That's why I asked for the whole component.

Comment: @Elias I added the states. 
for <GoogleMapReact> to render its shapes (<Circle>, <Polyline>) it has to be called through onGoogleApiLoaded

Comment: Yes, I understand. But you're only calling this onLoad. So you receive the data but the circles are never passed to the component, right? Event if you modified the object in place, how would the `GoogleMapReact` component know that the object changed and re-render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you can maintain and googleMapObj which we can use to call isApiLoaded function. And as mentioned below this is called in useEffect.

```js
const tags = [allJobsTag].concat(settings.jobs.filter((job) => !job.deleted));
const [tag, setTag] = useState(allJobsTag);
const [googleApiObj, setIsGoogleApiLoadedObj] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (googleApiObj) {
    const {
      map,
      maps
    } = googleApiObj;
    // or else call that isApiLoaded function and pass-on these arguments  
    renderGeoFences(map, maps)
  }
}, [googleApiObj, tag])

function renderGeoFences(map, maps) {
  _.map(geoFencesSites, (site) => {
    let circle = new maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: tag.id === 'all-jobs' ? "orange" : '#1aba8b26',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      fillColor: '#1aba8b1f',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      map,
      center: {
        lat: Number(site.location.latitude),
        lng: Number(site.location.longitude)
      },
      radius: site.fenceSize,
    });
  });
}

return ( <
  GoogleMapReact >
  zoom = {
    getMapZoom()
  }
  center = {
    {
      lat: centerLatitude,
      lng: centerLongitude
    }
  }
  options = {
    {
      fullscreenControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        position: 3
      },
    }
  }
  yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals onGoogleApiLoaded = {
    ({
      map,
      maps
    }) => setIsGoogleApiLoaded({
      map,
      maps
    })
  } >
  {
    renderAddresses()
  } {
    renderUsersLocation()
  } {
    renderHighlightedUserRoute()
  } <
  /GoogleMapReact>
)
```

Comment: I tried to edited your answer `setIsGoogleApiLoaded` -> `setIsGoogleApiLoadedObj` but it wouldn't let me

Answer (score -1):

You can re-render using React `useEffect` hook. In dependency array just give your state `tag` and now whenever `tag` changes its state, the `useEffect` function will runs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let apiIsLoaded = (map, maps) => {
    renderGeoFences(map, maps);
};
}, [tag]);
```

Comment: it looked promising, but if the apiIsLoaded call is in a useEffect, onGoogleApiLoaded can not recognize it.

Comment: I already tried before using useEffect like this: useEffect.... [map,maps] and now I also tried your solution exactly but as I said, apiIsLoaded was not recognized :(

Comment: If thats the issue, we can also move onGoogleApiLoaded logic to useEffect. Let me think.

Comment: can you try this `useEffect(() => {
    function apiIsLoaded (map, maps) {
    renderGeoFences(map, maps);
};
onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps)}
}, [tag]);`

Comment: Tried it now.. onGoogleApiLoaded is an attribute of <GoogleMapReact> and now that it's out of there and passed to the useEffect, it's just red and can't be found

Comment: oh! I'm not aware that onGoogleApiLoaded is an attribute of <GoogleMapReact>. Now thats become interesting problem.

Comment: Try this `useEffect(() => {
   window.location.reload();
}, [tag]);` this should solve your problem.

Comment: nice try.. but this just reloads the page as soon as its loaded :(

Comment: `const [skipInitial, setSkipInitial] = useState(true); useEffect(() => { if (skipInitial) setSkipInitial(false); if (!skipInitial) window.location.reload(); }, [tag]);`

Comment: using window.location.reload is not the approach at all :( I am working with a map modal. I can't have it reloaded everytime I change a tag, only rerender.

Comment: understood. For that usecase you can use `forceRender`. It will not reload whole but rerender component. `const [, forceRender] = useState({}); forceRender({});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235764/discussion-between-yogesh-yadav-and-zusman).